# Set display only field from select list

Tags: oracle-apex

I've started to learn APEX just recently.

I've a select list, called `LB_TEST1`, from which value I want to display in a display only field `TB_TEST4`

I've set up (inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173291/oracle-apex-list-of-values-select-value-and-use-in-sql-query-in-next-field)):

- `LB_TEST1`

  - select list (populated from a query)
  - action when value changed: `None (default)`
- `TB_TEST4`

  - based on: page item value
- also created a dynamic action:

  - when: `LB1_TEST` changes, no condition
  - action: `set value`
  - fire when result is `true`
  - set type: `static assignment`
  - value: `&LB_TEST1`
  - affected elements: `TB_TEST4`
- (fields not listed mainly contain default values)

What happens:
each time I run application at first change of `LB1_TEST`'s value `TB_TEST4` is filled by the OLD(!) value of `LB1_TEST`.
subsequent changes of `LB1_TEST` are not triggering change of `TB_TEST4`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your dynamic action as below,

- Change set type from *Static Assignment* to *JavaScript Expression*
- Change JavaScript Expression value from `&LB_TEST1` to `$v('LB1_TEST')`

Also, look at how session state works in Oracle APEX. The link in the question you have referred above is a good start --> [Doc Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35125/concept_ses.htm#BEIHBFJJ)

Demo Page Link --> https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=114083:1